# How to manually plot Box and Whisker graph?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

Box and Whisker graph displays the following information: max, min, mean, 75th percentile, 25th percentile. If I have these information, can I plot the corresponding B&W graph?

I have this data frame called TP.df:

```
        pb1    ag1     pb2     ag2     pb3    ag3
Nb      498    498      85      85      68     68
Min       0      0       0       0       0      0
Max    1.72    461   2.641   260.8     0.3    144
Mean   0.06   19.2    0.15   35.35    0.02   9.11
75_p   0.06     20    0.08      33    0.02      8
25_p   0.01     10       0      14    0.01      4
```

file:

```
,pb1,ag1,pb2,ag2,pb3,ag3
Nb,498,498,85,85,68,68
Min,0,0,0,0,0,0
Max,1.72,461,2.641,260.8,0.3,144
Mean,0.06,19.2,0.15,35.35,0.02,9.11
75_p,0.06,20,0.08,33,0.02,8
25_p,0.01,10,0,14,0.01,4
```

How can I have the corresponding Box and Whisker graph:

- it must show 6 boxes
- x axis : `pb1`, `ag1`, `pb2`, `ag2`, `pb3`, `ag3`
- y axis : `0` to `max(TP.df[Max,])`

Comment: Did you look at `? boxplot` and `? boxplot.stats`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `bxp` to make a boxplot from a five-number summary.

Does this do the sort of thing you want?

```
testdata=data.frame(R1=c(0,5,3,2,4),R2=c(1,7,3,2.8,6))
o=c(1,5,3,4,2) # the rows in increasing order
bxp.data=list(stats=data.matrix(testdata[o,]),n=rep(1,ncol(testdata)))
# the n=... parameter doesn't affect the plot, but it still needs to be there
bxp(bxp.data)
```

You can use standard graphical parameters (see `help(par)`) to label the axes and make it look pretty.

(Note: row numbers are off by one because the question was edited after I posted this answer.  I'll leave the answer as is so that it matches the first two comments.)

Comment: Can you explain the third line ? Why you used `o=c(1,5,3,4,2)` ?

Comment: The rows in your example are in the order min, max, mean, P_75, P_25.  For input to bxp, we need the numbers ordered from smallest to largest: that's row 1, row 5, row 3, row 4, row 2.

Comment: I do not think your answer is what I look for. when I try to plot my data with `bxp.data=list(stats=data.matrix(a[c(3,4,5,7,6),]),n=rep(1,ncol(a)))`, I notice that `max` of the first box is not the max given in the first column of the data frame.

Comment: what about if there was NA in my data frame ?

Comment: You've shown a data fram with only six rows: where do you get c(3,4,5,7,6) from?  I can import the data from your file and make the plot with `a=read.csv("testdata.csv"); rownames(a)=a[,1]; a=a[,-1]; bxp.data=list(stats=data.matrix(a[c(2,6,4,5,3),]),n=rep(1,ncol(a))); bxp(bxp.data)`.  It looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

that might be a solution:

```
  #create a dummy boxplot that you can modify the data easily
  z<- boxplot(1:10)

  #look at the outbut an assign yout data to stats
  z$stats<- your_data

  #use bxp to plot, via add you can combine all three
  bxp(z)
```

or use the bxp function from the beginning..
see also: 
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Box-plot-with-5th-and-95th-percentiles-instead-of-1-5-IQR-problems-implementing-an-existing-solution-td3456123.html

ben

Answer (score 1):

Using manual boxplot with `ggplot`, you can manipulate plot aesthetics and add other parameters:

```
ggplot()+geom_boxplot(aes(x=1, y = 2:5, lower = 3, upper = 4, middle = 3.5, ymin=2, ymax=5))
```